# How to set max length and order of collection

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, product-collection

I have 2 questions.

I've found this solution on stackOverflow:

```
class Page extends \RonisBT\Cms\Block\Page
{
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    public $catalogProductVisibility;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory, \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry, \RonisBT\Cms\Helper\Data $helper, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $helper, $data);
    }

    public function getFeaturedProducts(){
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured_product', '1');
        $collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

I use it for getting products which marked as featured.

Everything works ok, but I want **to order products by id and limit collection to 10 units**.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Use setSize function to limit for collection.
$collection->setSize(10);

Comment: @akgola, can you also describe what means that row?

Comment: I think the row sets visibility based off the product's visibility within a catalog, example a product is out of stock it can't be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setPageSize function to limit for collection and order by `product_id`.

```
$collection->setPageSize(10)->setOrder('product_id');
```

Comment: Please upvote my question )